# Learn Python the Hard Way, Exercise 48

Tags: python, tuples

I've been all day trying to solve the `test_errors()` function in "[Exercise 48: Advanced User Input](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html)" of the book [Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/).

`assert_equal()`, a function in the tests asks me for the tuples in order and I haven't been able to code it that way.

My loops always returns first the nouns and last the error tuples, I don't know how to break the loop so it starts again but with the right values to continue or whatever is necessary to sort this tuples in the order they should be.

Here's the code:

```
class Lexicon(object):

def scan(self, stringo):
    vocabulary = [[('direction', 'north'), ('direction', 'south'), ('direction',     'east'), ('direction', 'west')],
                    [('verb', 'go'), ('verb', 'kill'), ('verb', 'eat')],
                    [('stop', 'the'), ('stop', 'in'), ('stop', 'of')],
                    [('noun', 'bear'), ('noun', 'princess')],    # Remember numbers
                    [('error', 'ASDFADFASDF'), ('error', 'IAS')],
                    [('number', '1234'), ('number','3'), ('number', '91234')]]

    self.stringo = stringo
    got_word = ''
    value = []
    rompe = self.stringo.split() #split rompe en los espacios

    for asigna in vocabulary: 
        for encuentra in asigna:          
            if encuentra[1]  in rompe:
                value.append(encuentra)

    return value   

eLexicon = Lexicon()


from nose.tools import *
from ex48.ex48 import eLexicon 

def test_directions():
    assert_equal(eLexicon.scan("north"), [('direction', 'north')])
    result = eLexicon.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result, [('direction', 'north'),
                  ('direction', 'south'),
              ('direction', 'east')])

def test_verbs():
    assert_equal(eLexicon.scan("go"), [('verb', 'go')])
    result = eLexicon.scan("go kill eat")
    assert_equal(result, [('verb', 'go'),
                  ('verb', 'kill'),
                  ('verb', 'eat')])

def test_stops():
    assert_equal(eLexicon.scan("the"), [('stop', 'the')])
    result = eLexicon.scan("the in of")
    assert_equal(result, [('stop', 'the'),
                  ('stop', 'in'),
                  ('stop', 'of')])

def test_nouns():
    assert_equal(eLexicon.scan("bear"), [('noun', 'bear')])
    result = eLexicon.scan("bear princess")
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                  ('noun', 'princess')])

#def test_numbers():
#   assert_equal(lexicon.scan("1234"), [('number', 1234)])
#   result = lexicon.scan("3 91234")
#   assert_equal(result, [('number', 3),
#                 ('number', 91234)])

def test_errors():
    assert_equal(eLexicon.scan("ASDFADFASDF"), [('error', 'ASDFADFASDF')])
    result = eLexicon.scan("bear IAS princess")
    assert_equal(result, [('noun', 'bear'),
                  ('error', 'IAS'),
                  ('noun', 'princess')])

======================================================================
FAIL: tests.ex48_tests.test_errors
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/home/totoro/Desktop/Python/projects/ex48/tests/ex48_tests.py", line 43, in         test_errors
    ('noun', 'princess')])
AssertionError: Lists differ: [('noun', 'bear'), ('noun', 'p... != [('noun', 'bear'),     ('error', '...

First differing element 1:
('noun', 'princess')
('error', 'IAS')

- [('noun', 'bear'), ('noun', 'princess'), ('error', 'IAS')]
+ [('noun', 'bear'), ('error', 'IAS'), ('noun', 'princess')]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 5 tests in 0.006s
```

Many thanks in advance for taking the time.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please specify the exact piece of code that is raising the issue

Comment: Is `from ex48.ex48 import eLexicon` overwriting your defenition with something else?

Comment: Basically my question is how to sort a tuple in accordance to a list, not alphabetically, but in the order that list was created:     AssertionError: Lists differ: [('noun', 'bear'), ('noun', 'princess')('error', 'IAS' != [('noun', 'bear'), ('error', 'IAS',('noun', 'princess')]

First differing element 1:
('noun', 'princess')
('error', 'IAS')

- [('noun', 'bear'), ('noun', 'princess'), ('error', 'IAS')]
+ [('noun', 'bear'), ('error', 'IAS'), ('noun', 'princess')]
If I could sort the list of tuples Then that error would not arise. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: No, it's not overwriting anything. It's just the order

Comment: Please check that the indentation in your question matches that which you have locally.

Comment: Also, why have you modified [the tests](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html#what-you-should-test) in this way?

Comment: What I modified is just the class name and the imports because I couldn't get the test working, then I forgot to put it the way it was originally, but the substance of the code is there, unmodified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The words in the test are in the same order going in as coming out. As such you need to re-order your `for`-loops to iterate over the input first:

```
    value = []
    for rompe in stringo.split():
        for asigna in vocabulary:
            for encuentra in asigna:
                if encuentra[1] == rompe:
                    value.append(encuentra)
```

This will return the `encuentra`s in the correct order.

**Note 1**: You should not be hard-coding the numbers or errors.

**Note 2**: You can drastically reduce the complexity of this algorithm by using dictionary or two.

#### Example:

```
vocabulary = {
    'direction': 'north east south west up down left right back'.split(),
    'noun': 'bear princess door cabinet'.split(),
    'stop': 'the in of from at it'.split(),
    'verb': 'go kill eat stop'.split(),
}

'''
This creates a lookup using a dictionary-comprehension:
{'at': 'stop',
# [...]
 'up': 'direction',
 'west': 'direction'}
'''
classifications = {i: k for k, v in vocabulary.iteritems() for i in v}


def classify(word):
    try:
        return 'number', int(word)
    except ValueError:
        return classifications.get(word, 'error'), word


def scan(words):
    return [classify(word) for word in words.split()]
```

Comment: Thank you Johnsyweb, your solution helped me clarify the loops I had running. What you coded didn' append anything because pair[1] is taking the whole tuple and word is only the word, so they couldn't match. Again I thank you for your great help. I'm sorry, this is my first post here and I need to learn to post correctly.

Comment: Apologies, I'd missed that each element of `vocabulary` was another `list`. I've updated my answer accordingly. I'd recommend flattening this out to reduce the complexity, or better still, using a dictionary, like in my example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time Johnsyweb. That bit of code you've written is quite interesting and full of things I hadn't seen before. I will analyse it thoroughly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
    for word in self.stringo.split(): 
        for pair in vocabulary:             
            if pair[0][1] == word:
                value.append(pair[0])
            elif pair[1][1] == word:
                value.append(pair[1])
            elif pair[2][1] == word:
                value.append(pair[2])
            elif pair[3][1] == word:
                value.append(pair[3])
```

Answer (score 0):

I just finished this exercise, hope this gives some new ideas to some of you.
This is my solution:

```
#Set up datastructure
direction = ["north", "east", "south", "west", "up", "right", "down", "left", "back"]
verb = ["go", "stop", "kill", "eat"]
stop = ["the", "in", "of", "from", "at", "it"]
noun = ["door", "bear", "princess", "cabinet"]
vocabulary = [(direction, 'direction'), (verb, 'verb'), (stop, 'stop'), (noun, 'noun')]

def scan(sentence):
    #searches the words in the datastructure, if not found checks if it is an integer, if not returns error.
    results = []
    words = sentence.split()

    for word in words:
        found = False
        for category in vocabulary:
            if word.lower() in category[0]:
                results.append((category[1], word))
                found = True
            else:
                pass
        if found is False and isInt_str(word) is True:
            results.append(('number', int(word)))
        elif found is False and isInt_str(word) is False:
            results.append(('error', word))
        elif found is True:
            pass
        else:
            print("I'm terribly sorry, but something you entered is neither a word nor a number.")
    return results

def isInt_str(string):
    #returns True or False if string equals an integer. (i.e. 2 = True, 2*-2 = True 2**0,5 = False)
    string = str(string).strip()
    return string=='0' or (string if string.find('..') > -1 else string.lstrip('-+').rstrip('0').rstrip('.')).isdigit()
```